# requirejs.js single file with legacy codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Right now I'm rewriting a big chunck of legacy codes.
After I've build the single file using requirejs and added it on the last list of scripts it throws an error
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

```
<script src="/assets/js/fileinput.custom.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/helpers.js" cache="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/core.js" cache="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/app.js" cache="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/inline_edit.js" cache="false"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="/_assets/js/single-file-using-requirejs.js"></script>
```

My question is that is there a way I could build a single file using requirejs without affecting other legacy codes?

Currently i'm using grunt-contrib-requirejs

**Gruntfile.js**

```
requirejs: {
    build: {
        options: {
            mainConfigFile: '<%= globalConfig.scripts %>/main.js',
            baseUrl: "<%= globalConfig.scripts %>",
            name: "vendor/almond",
            include: ['main', 'requireLib'],
            out: "<%= globalConfig.scripts %>/<%= pkg.name %>.js",
            preserveLicenseComments: false,
            paths: {
                requireLib: 'vendor/require'
            },
        }
    }
}
```

The settings that I've implemented for requirejs and buildjs plain and simple.
Hope anyone can help me on this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you incorporating RequireJS into the bundle with the `requireLib` trick **and** using Almond?

Comment: So I have a wrong config? Ok, i just removed it sir, and still i have the same errors

Comment: and if i try to use this one
`<script data-main="/_assets/js/main" src="/_assets/js/vendor/require.js"></script>` it works

But when I try to use the singe build file
`<script src="/_assets/js/single-file-using-requirejs.js"></script>` it fails